# reading from start of RAM, and copy_to_user || how to get valid physical address of start of RAM

Tags: c, linux-kernel, memory-address

So I like to read the start of RAM maybe 1KB sized area. And copy it to user buffer.

How to do it

I assume when I do `copy_to_user(buf, (char *)0x00, count))` so here my copy_to_user guess that 0x00 is virtual address. So Is there any way I can get physical address of start of RAM. Is it possible in Linux kernel?

This is my code for read in char driver for kernel module

```
static ssize_t mychardev_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset)
{
    if (copy_to_user(buf, (char *)0x00, count)) {
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    return count;
}
```

So Idea is what ever data is found at the start of RAM I want to read it.

Or simply put it, what would be the valid address to start of RAM in above copy_to_user. I want first physical address. if Its not - 0x00 then what it is

**Update**

So now I am calling

```
long pfn=x/(4096);
if(pfn_valid(pfn))
{
```

So I found from address I can get page frame  number and so for this I need to devide my address to sizeof page. So on this system its 4096 bytes of single page ('s size)

But now my code not finding any valid address means all the address are invalid. Why is that and this message is keep printing in log `printk("whops not valid address\n")`

this is my full read code

```
static ssize_t mychardev_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset)
{
    uint8_t *data = "Hello from the kernel world!\n";
    size_t datalen = strlen(data);

    printk("Reading device: %d\n", MINOR(file->f_path.dentry->d_inode->i_rdev));

    if (count > datalen) {
    count = datalen;
    }

    long x=0xFFFF800000000000;
    while(1)
    {
        long pfn=x/(4096);
        if(pfn_valid(pfn))
        {
            x=x;
            printk("***********************\n***********\ncool valid\n");
            if (copy_to_user(buf, (char *)x, count)) 
            {
                return -EFAULT;
            }
            break;

        }
        else
        {
    
            x=x+0x0000000000000001;
            printk("whops not valid address\n");
        }   


    }
    
        
    
    return count;
}
```

**

**Update 2**

Now when I try addresses from `long x=0x0000000000FFFFFF;` it says while reading the char device that cat :/dev/mychar-0 Bad Address

why is that

```
static ssize_t mychardev_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *offset)
{
    uint8_t *data = "Hello from the kernel world!\n";
    size_t datalen = strlen(data);

    printk("Reading device: %d\n", MINOR(file->f_path.dentry->d_inode->i_rdev));

    if (count > datalen) {
    count = datalen;
    }

    long x=0x0000000000FFFFFF;
    while(1)
    {
        long pfn=x/(4096);
        if(pfn_valid(pfn))
        {
            x=x;
            printk("***********************\n***********\ncool valid\n");
            if (copy_to_user(buf, (char *)x, count)) 
            {
                return -EFAULT;
            }
            break;

        }
        else
        {
    
            x=x+0x0000000000000001;
            printk("whops not valid address\n");
        }   


    }
    
        
    
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Show pfn_valid() function

Comment: @OSdev its from kernel headers https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arc/include/asm/page.h#L106

Comment: Are you writing a kernel or doing this in usual linux kernel

Comment: @OSdev I have created the kernel out of tree module that creates char device and I am trying to read from beginning of RAM

Comment: for pfn_valid I have included asm/page.h header file in my kernel module c file

Comment: I never got into linux source code which logic they use to do but i have written many unix xv6 like os and and as it is my os it is my memory if i want to read i can just point to it and if i want to copy from one memory area just simply just use pointers or use assembly code.

Comment: But i think what causing you problem can be paging have you mapped that page into you directory entry ttable

Comment: @OSdev `have you mapped that page into you directory entry ttable` u mean I need to create virtual address mapping page to that address  before accessing that physical address `x=0x0000000000FFFFFF`

Comment: @OSdev oh Of course. if that u mean then u are right. Working now. Accessing physical memory I guess this way.  is this physical memory access. Can u tell?

Comment: Is it working now or not

Comment: @OSdev yes now it's working thanks

Comment: But now i have a doubt after reading about pfn_valid() it takes a page number and checks if there is page of that number means it checks according to size of physical memory and returns true or false. Than if the system for which you are writing if had memory of that much size it should have returned true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242752/discussion-between-osdev-and-user786).